# Add current timestamp to Spark dataframe but partition it by the current date without adding it to the dataframe

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, parquet, partition-by

I understand we can add current timestamp to a dataframe by doing this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.current_timestamp    
df.withColumn("time_stamp", current_timestamp())
```

However if we'd like to partition it by the current date at the point of saving it as a parquet file by deriving it from the timestamp without adding it to the dataframe, would that be possible?
What I am trying to achieve would be something like this:

```
df.write.partitionBy(date("time_stamp")).parquet("/path/to/file")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. `partitionBy` must specify the name of a column or columns of the dataset. In addition, when reading table data, spark implements Partition Discovery according to the storage structure.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @过过招 , [partitionBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.partitionBy.html) takes in a column , and you cannot supply a calculated field

You can implicitly create a column using [current_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.current_date.html?highlight=current_date) , and use that in `partitionBy` , the `current_date` column that you have created will anyways not be part of your data dump

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.current_date    
df.withColumn("current_date", current_date())

df.write.partitionBy(current_date).parquet("/path/to/file")
```

Comment: Thanks @vaebhav .. If we use Presto etc to read from the parquet files, I presume there will be an option to either consider or ignore the columns used for partitioning while reading from the files as a table.